# How to change google map's marker size when moving it on map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout

How to change google map's marker when moving it on the map.

When I move on the map, change marker's size to small and when it's in a fixed position change its size to large.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do it when the events 'dragstart' and 'dragend' are triggered.

Example:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(event) {
    //increase size
    marker.setIcon({url : 'path_to_img', scaledSize: {height: 12 , width: 12}})
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
   //decrease size
   marker.setIcon({url : 'path_to_img', scaledSize: {height: 64 , width: 64}})
  });
```